# Centos -- Yum Update Error – “HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden”

Tags: docker, proxy, centos, containers, yum

I’ve recently spun up a Docker container running CentOS Linux version 7.  In my office, we have a proxy server, so once the container was up, I consoled in and set the proxy manually:

```
[me@8adfa83bb9e2 /home/me]#
[me@8adfa83bb9e2 /home/me]# export http_proxy="http://10.10.10.101:8888"
[me@8adfa83bb9e2 /home/me]#
```

On a separate SO post, I learned about setting the proxy in the `/etc/yum.conf` file.  So I added the following line to my `/etc/yum.conf` file:

```
proxy=http://10.10.10.101:8888
```

And then I did a “`yum clean metadata`”:

```
[me@8adfa83bb9e2 /home/me]# yum clean metadata
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Cleaning repos: base extras updates
0 metadata files removed
0 sqlite files removed
0 metadata files removed
[me@8adfa83bb9e2 /home/me]#
```

At this point, I figured I was home free.  I did a “`yum update`”:

```
[me@8adfa83bb9e2 /home/me]#
[me@8adfa83bb9e2 /home/me]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=container error was
14: HTTP Error 403 – Forbidden
...and then a lot more stuff here...
```

Hmm.  “***HTTP Error 403***”.  That’s a new one for me; I’m used to running “`yum update`” and it just automagically works.

This isn’t a DNS problem; the Docker container can resolve and ping `mirrorlist.centos.org`.  I tried to use wget to pull down that URL, but the container doesn’t have wget installed.  When I try the same thing from the host machine:

```
me@hostmachine:/home/me$
me@hostmachine:/home/me$
me@hostmachine:/home/me$ sudo wget http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=container
[1] 7039
[2] 7040
[3] 7041
[2]   Done                    arch=x86_64
me@hostmachine:/home/me$
Redirecting output to ‘wget-log’.

[1]-  Exit 8                  sudo wget http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7
[3]+  Done                    repo=os
me@hostmachine:/home/me$
me@hostmachine:/home/me$
me@hostmachine:/home/me$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 382 Jan 21 19:55 wget-log
me@hostmachine:/home/me$
me@hostmachine:/home/me$
me@hostmachine:/home/me$ more wget-log
--2021-01-21 19:55:31--  http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7
Resolving mirrorlist.centos.org (mirrorlist.centos.org)... 147.75.69.225, 18.225.36.18, 67.219.148.138, ...
Connecting to mirrorlist.centos.org (mirrorlist.centos.org)|147.75.69.225|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2021-01-21 19:55:31 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.

me@hostmachine:/home/me$
me@hostmachine:/home/me$
```

(Yes, the host machine has the correct proxy settings.  It is not a Centos machine.)

Soooooooo…  It looks like the yum service is “unavailable” from my host system.  But I’ve run “`yum update`” on many, many other Centos machines in my environment.  No idea what might be different here.  Has anyone seen this before?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anyone who may be looking at this post...  The issue was a proxy server problem.  Once I set the proxy server settings on ***both*** the host and container, the issue went away.  I think in the above post, I'd set the proxy on the container, but not the host, and the host was NAT'ing the container's IP address when doing a "yum update."

Comment: Hi Pete, I seem to be experiencing this as well.
Could you clarify how you set the proxy server on the host?

Comment: @gfields Sure, I'll try.  I did two things.  On my Ubuntu host, I set the proxy directly on the command line like this:  
--------------------------------------------
export http_proxy="http://10.10.10.110:8080"
export https_proxy="http://10.10.10.110:8080"
--------------------------------------------
Then, I also edited the /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf file, so that it read like this:
--------------------------------------------
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://10.10.10.110:8080";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://10.10.10.110:8080";
--------------------------------------------

Comment: @gfields - okay, that editing looks terrible.  But reach out if you still have problems.  The fix wasn't hard, once I used those two command line commands and modified the proxy.conf file.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Pete, I'll try it!

Comment: It turns out the problem was in the configuration on the proxy server itself. We had to explicitly allow requests to some specific outside domains.